# How to auto mount drive when logging in?

Tags: mount, login, fstab

I am trying to auto-mount a partition inside my home folder, when I login. But I have no idea on how to do this. I did try auto-mounting it at boot-up. But this didn't work. I suspect that is because my home folder is encrypted. I did this in fstab, using the following format.

UUID=####... /home/*user*/destination    ext4    defaults        0       0

when doing this the folder shows up empty. I have tried using Disk to setup an auto-mount. This caused my computer not boot, until I removed its edit form fstab.

I am looking for idea on how to solve this problem thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a more elegant solution, but provided that you can't mount something with fstab when it's in an encrypted directory, you can simply use cron to run mount once you log in. This way your cron script runs after you decrypt your home directory.

I've had to mount some SMB shares this way because fstab would fail every time.